# Does rebasing a branch chnage the current branch or the branch which we rebased

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was going through the documentation of git rebase and git merge. I understood the difference and rebasing almost, but i have one doubt. Does rebase effect the current branch or the rebased branch.

For Example:

I have a branch `new-branch` checked out from `master` and both `master` and `new-checkout` branch progressed, Now after pushing some commits in `new-branch`, I want to rebase it with origin master.

I ran this command in `my-branch`

```
git rebase master
```

I did the rebasing, I know that git will put some new commits of `my-branch` on the top of current `master` branch head.

Now my question is that, if i will force push from the `my-branch`, then will it change the code of `my-branch` or it will change the remote `master` branch.

Hope you understood my question, please let me know if anything is confusing in my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: git rebase master, will put the commits from the master branch on top of the 'my-branch' not what you are saying...

Comment: On which branch you are pushing ???

Comment: I want to push on `my-branch` after rebase with master

Comment: No. I will rebase master after going to my-branch and will push in my-branch after rebasing. And it will put my-branch commits on top of master head. See here  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: if you use the following command `git push origin my-branch`

Then it will push your changes to the `my-branch` present on your GitHub, code present in `my-branch` on GitHub will get change, not the code present in master branch, master branch will remain unaffected

Comment: git  rebase will replay your changes 
If you are in `my-branch` and doing `git rebase master` it will put the changes in master on top of your `my-branch`

I will suggest you to execute the `git log` command before and after executing both the command , then you will have better picture

Comment: What `git rebase` does is that it *copies* some commits, and then moves the *current branch name* to point to the tip of the last-copied commit. It has no effect on any existing commits—but if you're currently finding the tip commit of `my-branch` using the *name* `my-branch`, and you *move* the name `my-branch` to point to some new copies of old commits, you will no longer find the old commits, but rather the new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rebase master` will change the commit history on `new-branch`.

As below graphs, assume the original commit history is:

```
A---B---C---G---H   master
         \
          D---E---F  my-branch
```

After executing `git rebase master`, it will rebase the changes from `my-branch` to `master` branch. And the commit history will look like:

```
A---B---C---G---H---D'---E'---F'   my-branch
                |
              master
```

If you force push for `my-branch` to remote (`git push -f origin my-branch`), the remote `my-branch` will change the version as `F'` as above graph.

Comment: When will the master branch change as `F'` ? if i checkout to master and do git push master then will it change like `F'` ?

Comment: `master` branch is not changed, it still point to commit `H`. If you push `master` branch again, it will show `every thing up-to-date`.